# can I use Jquery blockui(plugin) code withouut Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, struts-1

Im newbie to Jquery please help......

I have one page which has multiple links. When user click on one link before it completes the process backside and loads the page, he is hitting another links without wait which causing issue. I'm looking for the solution to avoid user to hit multiple clicks at a time.

To solve, I have found the Jquery BlockUI plugin and downloaded the (production version of) jquery.blockUi.min.js from the link https://github.com/malsup/blockui/and added below code snippet

```
$('#linkX').click(function() { 
$.blockUI({ message: '<h1><img src="busy.gif" /> Just a moment...</h1>' }); 
});
```

Now when I click on any link (all the links have same class name) immediately this code blocks the page and display popup with message "just a moment", and then once the java process/request (default submit which is form action='/xxx') finishes (it does process some action and update the database too) the page refresh and then automatically the page unblocks. This is perfectly working fine. But I wonder am I using this blockUI feature correctly? Is it can be used without Ajax, and just with regular java server (form action) request?

is this jquery.blockUi.min.js safe to download and use as I'm working for federal company?

Here I have everything working fine with Java+Struts1.x. Im just using this blockui feature just to avoid the user to click on multiple links at the same time - by disabling the page with some popup message few seconds until the page refreshes with new data.

Since Im not using Ajax here, is there any other easy solution that I can use or is this good solution?

Answer (score 0):

I don't claim to be an expert, but I am using it the same way on my Python Django web-site, in order to load a processing-intensive page (obviously it has to be used this way, since the HTML won't load before the Controller has finished the processing task).

Just remember to include:

```
$(window).on('unload', function()
{
    $.unblockUI();
});
```

in order to unblock the UI when the page changes (or else when you hit the "back" button, you might still see a blocked page).

Another old-school way is to "disable" all the links/button on the page, when the user clicks on one, so that the user cannot interact with it while it loads.